# Java regex to capture all words in strings

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regex able to capture all the words in a string.

I have below input strings

1. JOHN SMITH MR
2. JOHN MR
3. J MISS

Expected output

1. {"JOHN", "SMITH", "MR"}
2. {"JOHN", "MR"}
3. {"J", "MISS"}

I have written the regex below which is working perfectly fine but it is not working for input string 2 and 3. The input string should only have alphabetical characters (no numbers or special characters).

`((?:[a-z]*[a-z]+)).*?((?:[a-z][a-z]+)).*?((?:[a-z][a-z]+))`

If the input string contains numbers like `JOHN  12345` then the regex should not capture anything.

Could you please help me to improve my regex to capture the expected result?

Comment: You can match with `[a-zA-Z ]*` and if its true, you split on spaces

Comment: do you have at most three words per string?

Comment: Some time it will 2 words, sometime it will be 3. The count of words is not consistent.

Comment: That could probably be simplified to something more like ```Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-z]+).*?([a-z]{2,}).*?([a-z]+)?");``` (you can restore the non-captures if you really want them but don't double brackets redundantly). You're attempting to match *three things only*

Answer (score 0):

can i suggest alternative?
use string split() method together with regex. See below

```
        String[] arr = {"JOHN SMITH MR",
                "JOHN MR",
                "J MISS",
        "JOHN 1234"};

        for (String s : arr) {
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matcher(s);
            if(m.find()){
                continue;
            }
            String[] arr2 = s.split(" ");
            log.info("arr2 = {}", Arrays.asList(arr2));
        }
```

There you have your output

Answer (score 0):

Have an existing code the extract the first name and Title form the input rawNameString. The code is working perfectly if the input string contain only first-Name and Title like( "JOHN MR") but it will not work if theinput string contain first-Name, middle name and Title like ("JOHN SMITH MR"). In that the case Title is getting mapped with incorrect value.
The Goal is to extract only  first-Name and title only.

**Existing Code:**

```
Pattern  NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("((?:[a-z]*[a-z]+))" + ".*?" + "((?:[a-z][a-z]+))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        String rawNameString = "JOHN MR";

        Name name = new Name();
        Matcher nameMatcher = NAME_PATTERN.matcher(rawNameString);
        if (nameMatcher.find()) {
            //tile
            name.setTitle(nameMatcher.group(2));
            //firstname
            name.setFirstName(nameMatcher.group(1));
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Name");
        }
```

I have modified the code to capture the first name and Title irrespective to number of words in input string.

```
Pattern  NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]*$");
        String rawNameString = "JOHN SMITH MR";

        Name name = new Name();
        Matcher matcher = NAME_PATTERN.matcher(rawNameString);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            List<String> nameList = Arrays.asList(rawNameString.split("\\s+"));
            if(nameList.isEmpty())
                throw new Exception("Invalid Name ");
            name.setFirstName(nameList.get(0));
            name.setTitle(nameList.get(nameList.size()-1));
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Name ");
        }
```

I was looking to change the regex instead of changing the Java code.

Comment: *The Goal is to extract only first-Name and title only.* Then all this regex stuff is overkill. ```String.split("\\s+");``` will do it for you where the second of two tokens matches a title

Comment: @g00se, yeah that's correct but if the input string contains numeric value then it should not captured anything. If we used only split then numeric will also get captured.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this one:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+) *([a-zA-Z]+)* *([a-zA-Z]+)* *$
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

Used regex:

```
"[^a-zA-Z\\s]"
```

The regex is matching non-letter or non-space.

See regex in context and testbench, below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input1 = "JOHN SMITH MR";
    String input2 = "JOHN MR";
    String input3 = "J MISS";
    String input4 = "JOHN  12345";

    List<String> inputList = Arrays.asList(input1, input2, input3, input4);

    Pattern findAnyNonLetterNonSpacePattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z\\s]");
    for (String input : inputList) {
        if (findAnyNonLetterNonSpacePattern.matcher(input).find()) continue;
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(input.split("\\s+"));
        System.out.println(stringList);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[JOHN, SMITH, MR]
[JOHN, MR]
[J, MISS]
```